# How to get full strings in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy to extract a list from a website.If I use the the following code:

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="mainframe"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/span[2]/text()').extract()
```

It returns

```
[u'A sample String with dot dot dot in the end...',
u'And some other string ...',
u'Another similar string with dots in the end...',
u'Can some one help with preventing my string from being trun...']
```

Whereas , when I use without "/text()" as shown in the below code i.e.

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="mainframe"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/span[2]').extract()
```

I get following output:

```
[u'<span title= A sample String with dot dot dot in the end and plus something> some_text </span>',
 u'<span title=And some other string and plus something> some_text </span>',
 u'<span title=Another similar string with dots in the end and plus something> some_text </span>',
 u'<span title=Can some one help with preventing my string from being truncated and plus something> some_text </span>']
```

How to get the full string without these dots?

Comment: `text()` selects text nodes, `.extract()` will give you text content of text nodes, there's no transformation in Scrapy selector methods, so if you get "...", it must mean that the "..." are in the HTML in the first place. Please provide sample HTML input for the community to help you further.

Comment: I edited the output without using "/text()" .And it shows the full strings . I am sorry I can't give the real script ,they are some private addresses.Is it something to do with unicode ??

Comment: Please provide some input, and obfuscate any sensitive data. Your issue is not related to unicode. You can try the `string()` function in XPath, like in this loop: `for span in response.xpath('//*[@id="mainframe"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/span[2]'): print span.xpath('string(.)').extract()` ; this will get you the string representation of each selected `<span>` element

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following code:

`item['name'] = site.xpath('a[1]/text()').re('(\w+)')`